# Using appengine with arch and zsh unable to find goapp

Tags: google-app-engine, go, zsh, zshrc, google-app-engine-go

I am new to appengine and have installed google-cloud-sdk from the AUR(arch user repository) and and the google-appengine-go extention at /opt/google-cloud-sdk

thanks to this I am able to run a dev server using

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

But when using **goapp serve** I found

```
goapp: command not found
```

After adding `/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine:$PATH` to my $PATH variable in **zshrc** and running **goapp serve** i now get the error.

```
zsh: permission denied: goapp
```

if **sudo goapp serve**

```
sudo: goapp: command not found
```

Due to this I am unable to use the updated sdk to run tests using **goapp test**
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Make sure you are in the same terminal session where you have updated the PATH. check `which goapp` and `sudo which goapp`.

Comment: `which goapp` returns `goapp not found`
`sudo which goapp` returns `which: no goapp in <the path valur>`
but when I `ls /opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine` i can see the goapp binary.
But cannot use it even if i use the full path or sudo the full path.

Comment: Can you reinstall or do a clean install of the google-cloud-sdk to try to see if it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think I figured out how it usually works.

1. You download the google cloud sdk (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads)
2. After downloading and unzipping to the folder where you want to use it you have to executet the ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh.
   Appengine is not part of the download.
   It can be chosen with that install.sh script.
   it will download items like appengine.
   Afterwards you have a folder called
   platform/google_appengine
   as you mentioned yourself.
3. You might have to change execution permissions like
   chmod 755 platform/google_appengine/go*
4. Add folder platform/google_appengine to the PATH if not done already. 
   The command "which" will not show non-executable binaries.
   If you did not change permissions it will not show the path, even being within the PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks janumar,
I had installed the appengine package by using `gcloud components install app-engine-go`. by `chmod 755 platform/google_appengine/go*` the issue was solved and now I am able to run goapp.

Note to use goapp test I need to specify the folder containing the tests. else getting an error. maybe theirs a way around that as well.

I changed the permissions but which shows goapp with its path. Any suggestions?